# The get in laravel doesn't find any page

Tags: php, laravel, routes, get, localhost

I am very a beginner in Laravel
I launch my laravel project on localhost

```
<http://localhost/ecommerce/public/>
```

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

this give me the welcome page

But I want to add about page but it always say "404 Not found"
and that's my code:

```
Route::get('/about', function () {
    return view('about');
});
```

I made a file in views and called it "about.blade.php"

when I type to view about like this :

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('about');
});
```

and remove the welcome get, it works and give the about page

but when I put it in get "/about" it always doesn't work, even if I just type "string"
why it can't recognize get "/about"?

Comment: Route caching? If the route doesn't show up in `php artisan route:list` try ` php artisan route:clear`

Answer (score 0):

You should run the project with `php artisan serve` in terminal or in the server you have to change document root and remove the public in URL

the reason is  the extra public in your url